# How can I upgrade ONLY Drupal core with composer?

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I knew that Drush make files were being phased out, but I kept using them, because in my opinion Composer isn't the best package manager in the known universe.  It updates too much or too little, has uninformative error messages, 
and takes a lot more ram than necessary.  Don't get me wrong, I still used composer, but not for Drupal core updates, because those are more important and sometimes security releases.

But, in 8.4, Drush 9 is required, and in Drush 9 make files don't work at all.

My concern is this: I have some wildcards in my composer.json similar to the ones mentioned in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2609568 which tell composer where to find my modules' composer.json files.  Yet, when I run

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

Whether or not I run it --with-dependencies, it will always go into the merge-plugin include paths and update all of those packages as well.  Now, if my site is out in production, I would like an easy way to update core and core's vendor files WITHOUT updating a bunch of contrib modules' libraries which I do not care about.  What if core releases a security update?  I want to be able to conveniently update core and *only* core quickly.  With Drush make, this was simple.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this with composer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do two things.

1. I use [`webflo/drupal-core-strict`](https://github.com/webflo/drupal-core-strict) in my `composer.json` to make sure the same tested core dependencies are the ones used in my project.
2. I pin both `drupal/core` and `webflo/drupal-core-strict` to an exact Drupal version so I can regression test and know exactly what I am deploying.

So, my projects looks like

```
"require": {
    "drupal/core": "8.3.6",
    "webflo/drupal-core-strict": "8.3.6",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
    "drush/drush": "~8.0",
    "drupal/console": "~1.0",
},
```

And where there is a new core version, I `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-strict` and then double check the lockfile.

Comment: I've also been using drupal-core-strict but I've always been struggling with weird conflicts with it, see https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6131

Comment: So if I use this `webflo/drupal-core-strict` package, will it be available at the same time as a drupal update?  Say 8.3.7 were to be released right this instant, when would webflo/drupal-core-strict 8.3.7 be released?

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch Immediately, no.  It is maintained by someone heavily involved with core development, but not an official Drupal package.  However, it has always been available very quickly.  I think the last time there was an announcement to "get ready to update sites" b/c security, it was ready in ~15min.

Comment: Does this also work for updates to drupal 8.5.0?

Comment: @LarS Yes, this will work for updates between minor versions.

Comment: I had some problems updating to Drupal 8.5.0, but finally I got it work, see https://github.com/webflo/drupal-core-strict/issues/5

Comment: This does not work for an upgrade to Drupal 8.7.  I have not been able to figure out how to update it using composer without also updating all contrib modules.

Comment: @arnoldbird `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-strict composer/installers --with-dependencies` should do the trick.